# Map first element of stream differently than rest

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Is there a way in Java's Stream API to map first element of stream differently than other?

Equivalent of this code:

```
List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<fooList.size(); i++) {
    Foo foo = fooList.get(i);
    Foo modifiedFoo = foo.getModifiedFoo();
    if (i == 0) {
        barList.add(new Bar(modifiedFoo, false));
    }else {
        barList.add(new Bar(modifiedFoo, true));
    }
}

Stream<Bar> = barList.stream();
```

Note: I already have a stream setup and I would want some operation after first mapping

```
fooList.stream()
        .map(Foo::getModifiedFoo)
        .(May be Some operation here to get different new Bar for first modifiedFoo)
        .map(modifiedFoo -> new Bar(modifiedFoo, true));
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would get the first element, create a `Stream` out of it and apply the needed mappings. Then, I'd take the rest of the list, create a stream out of it and apply the different mappings. Then `concat` the streams. Something like this:

```
Stream<Bar> first = Stream.of(fooList.get(0))
    .map(Foo::getModifiedFoo)
    .map(modifiedFoo -> new Bar(modifiedFoo, false));

Stream<Bar> others = fooList.subList(1, fooList.size()).stream()
    .map(Foo::getModifiedFoo)
    .map(modifiedFoo -> new Bar(modifiedFoo, true));

Stream<Bar> bars = Stream.concat(first, others).flatMap(s -> s);
```

---

Another approach:

```
Stream<Bar> bars = IntStream.range(0, fooList.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new Bar(fooList.get(i).getModifiedFoo(), i > 0));
```

This way is succinct and does the job pretty well.

Comment: I like the last approach, it's clever, compact and uncluttered.  nice!

Comment: Sadly only works for a List. I have stream to start with.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to iterate over the indices, then mapToObj to create an object for that index, and finally collect into a list:

```
List<Bar> barList = IntStream.range(0, fooList.size())
                             .mapToObj(i -> (i == 0 ? new Bar (fooList.get(i), false) : 
                                                      new Bar(fooList.get(i),true)))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What would be more readable though, is doing the first item handling outside the loop, and using IntStream starting with 1.

Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/cqA4TG) using simple lists.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose two ways but I find your way straighter.

With `IntStream` such as :

```
List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0, fooList.size())
         .forEach(i->{
                if (i == 0) {
                    barList.add(new Bar(foo, false));
                }else {
                    barList.add(new Bar(foo, true));
                }
         }
);
```

It is not a real functional approach (`forEach()` use and no `Collector`) because it maintains the current index of the List.

As alternative, you could use a more functional approach but I don't find it straighter either :

```
List<Bar> barList = IntStream.range(0, fooList.size())
                             .mapToObj(i->{
                                    Foo foo = fooList.get(i);
                                    if (i == 0) {
                                        return new Bar(foo, false);
                                    }
                                    return new Bar(foo, true));                                     
                             })
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: problem is that I already have a map before required operation in question.
`fooList.stream().map(FooUtility::getModifiedFoo)._Some operation here for first modifiedFoo to get new Bar_.map(modifiedFoo -> new Bar(modifiedFoo, true));`

Comment: Can be simplified to: `.mapToObj(i -> new Bar (fooList.get(i), i != 0))`

Answer (score 1):

Although I think the accepted answer is better, here is an alternate approach.

```
    int[] counter = {-1};

    Stream<Bar> barListStream = fooList.stream().map(foo -> {
          counter[0]++;
          return new Bar(mfoo.getModifiedFoo(), counter[0]>0);
       }).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an AtomicBoolean initially set to true to determine when is the first item.

```
    final AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    System.out.println("** Print all numbers 1..10");
    IntStream.range(1, 11).forEach(number -> {
        System.out.print((first.get() ? "" : ",") + number);
        first.set(false);
    });
    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an object to hold a flag e.g. AtomicBoolean or AtomicInteger - that you can reset on first or nth iteration (you would need something like AtomicInteger or some Integer holder to reset on nth iteration) e.g. following code using HashMap as the holder class - will print first line of the stream differently than the other lines:

```
    Map<String, Boolean> firstTime = new HashMap<>(Map.of("firstTime", true)); // to make the map modifiable
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        lines.forEachOrdered(line -> System.out.println(firstTime.remove("firstTime") != null ? ("firstTime: " + line) : line));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Stream<Bar> barStream = barList.stream();

List<Bar> bars = barStream.skip(1)
                   .map(modifiedFoo -> new Bar(modifiedFoo, false))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

barStream.findFirst()
     .map(modifiedFoo -> new Bar(modifiedFoo, true))
     .ifPresent(bars::add);
```